On Azure DevOps is there any way to make the Environments view more useful?
My team has a pretty decent DevOps process built around Terraform and ADO pipelines. The weak point is ADO's Environments page. It doesn't show anything useful.
We have about two dozen deployments across 4 different products. When I look at the Environments page what I want to see is

The name of the Environment
The name of the deployment pipeline that was last run
What branch and/or commit was last deployed
The date of the last deployment

What I actually get to see is

The name of the Environment
The name of the deployment pipeline that was last run
The build number
The date of when the Enviroment itself was last modified

For each environment I have to click through to the environment to see the date of the last deployment, and through two pages to see the branch and commit that was last deployed.
Does anyone know if it's possible to improve the Environments display to something useful, or if there is some ADO plugin that can do this?

As a workaround, have you considered customising the build number to show the branch/commi and the date?

On Azure DevOps, no such built-in options to let the page a an environment can show all the information you want. I also searched on the Marketplace, did not find available Azure DevOps extensions can do this.
If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on Developer Community. This will make it more convenient for the Azure DevOps engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

MS Developer Community reports are a total waste of time. I've ever seen a single thing reported there fixed or implemented in years. This particular issue is already reported there, but nothing will happen. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/In-the-Environment-page-the-Last-Activit/10513811

@Neutrino, This is not a problem/bug on the Environment page. It just does not display the information wanted by you. So, you should "Suggest a Feature" instead of "Report a Problem" on Developer Community. As far as I know, a feature request has more vote-up, the Azure DevOps engineer teams will take more priority on it.
